# How to calculate the second Tuesday of said month of said year in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make a program that calculates how long it will be until the next Patch Tuesday by finding the second Tuesday of the Month and then calculating how long it is until then.

I'm trying to figure out how to get Visual Basic to find the second Tuesday of the month.

Comment: Something like `dateserial(2020,MonthNumber,1)-weekday(dateserial(2020,MonthNumber,1),vbWednesday)+14`

Comment: That helps a lot actually... Need to debug it on my end though but that has got me quite far, thanks!